# SQL Server Cross Reference Query

Tags: sql

I have limited experience with SQL and I am trying to build a query that 'automatically' uses the xyzDesc record in place of xyzID references in the result of the query.

I've included a sample of what I am looking for. It is important to keep in mind, that the recordset I am trying to produce has ~ 35 columns (where it is necessary to initially outer join 3 very large tables) where ~10 columns need to be xref as I hope will be demonstrated by the example. Additionally, the database I am querying has the underlining tables containing **millions of rows**.

`Project` table:

```
projectID   projectDesc capitalSpend    regionID    statusID
-------------------------------------------------------------    
1           Project A   200             1           7
2           Project B   300             1           2
3           Project C   200             1           5
4           Project D   100             2           4
5           Project E   300             2           3
6           Project F   500             3           1
7           Project G   400             3           1
```

`StatusXref` table

```
statusID    statusDesc
------------------------    
1           Proposed
2           Prelim
3           Scheduled
4           Execute
5           Completed
6           On Hold
7           Decline
```

`RegionXref` table:

```
regionID    regionDesc
------------------------
1           New York
2           Houston
3           Los Angeles
4           Chicago
5           Denver
6           Dallas
7           Boston
```

Expected results when executing query:

```
projectID   projectDesc capitalSpend    Region         Status
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1       Project A       200         New York       Decline
    2       Project B       300         New York       Prelim
    3       Project C       200         New York       Completed
    4       Project D       100         Houston        Execute
    5       Project E       300         Houston        Scheduled
    6       Project F       500         Los Angeles    Proposed
    7       Project G       400         Los Angeles    Proposed
```

This seems like it should be 'easy' as it would be a simple vlookup in excel but I'm reluctant to pull all the data into excel and then do these lookups as excel row limitations prevent full data.

Comment: Be assured you are doing the right thing moving from Excel to a database. Now... what version of SQL? (i.e. SQL Server,Oracle, MySQL) What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select p.projectID, p.projectDesc, p.capitalSpend, r.regionDesc, s.statusDesc 
from Project p
inner join StatusXref s on p.statusID = s.statusID
inner join RegionXref r on p.regionID = r.regionID
```

Answer (score 0):

A `JOIN` is exactly what you are looking for. There are several types of [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), but the most common one is an inner join.

Example query:

```
SELECT p.projectID, P.projectDesc, P.capitalSpend, R.regionDesc, S.statusDesc 
FROM Project P
JOIN StatusXref S ON P.statusID = S.statusID
JOIN RegionXref R ON P.regionID = R.regionID;
```

This SQLFiddle will let you run queries on your small dataset. Be sure to use the select the correct version of SQL in the top left corner.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ebc89

---

P.S. When querying on your large dataset, you may find the `LIMIT` clause to be useful to test and see if your query is working properly without running across the millions of rows.